# Fielded Relation's Field not showing in Views

Tags: views

I'm trying to implement a "rating" system with Relation module. I have a Relation Type defined from a user --> node. The Relation Type has an Integer field to hold the rating.

I want to produce a view that shows the number of ratings and average rating. To start, I created a view with a list of nodes. I previously created a few "rating" relations between users and the nodes in the view, which can be seen in the Relations tab in content.

In views UI Advanced section, I added the Relationship from the node to its Relation. I added a view field for the Integer field on the Relation.

The label for the rating field shows, but the number is empty, even for relations I know are there.

Here is an export of the view:

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'offer_ratings';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'Offer Ratings';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Offer Ratings';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '100';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* Relationship: Content: Relation: rated by (node → relation) */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['relation_base_right_rated']['id'] = 'relation_base_right_rated';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['relation_base_right_rated']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['relation_base_right_rated']['field'] = 'relation_base_right_rated';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['relation_base_right_rated']['r_index'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['relation_base_right_rated']['entity_deduplication_right'] = 0;
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
/* Field: Relation: Rating */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_rating']['id'] = 'field_rating';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_rating']['table'] = 'field_data_field_rating';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_rating']['field'] = 'field_rating';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_rating']['relationship'] = 'relation_base_right_rated';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_rating']['settings'] = array(
  'thousand_separator' => '',
  'prefix_suffix' => 1,
);
/* Sort criterion: Content: Post date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'offer' => 'offer',
);

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'offer-ratings';
```

Comment: I recommend doing this with EntityReference fields. I rebuilt the rating system by creating a "Rating" content type with a field that can relate it to my nodes. I can show rating stats in Views fields now.

Answer (score 0):

Joe,

The best way to do a rating system in Drupal is to use Five Star: https://drupal.org/project/fivestar.

It comes with views integration out of the box. You add a rating field to your content type, place it in the display, render your entity in a view, or create a fielded view if you prefer the Drupal 6 way, and you're done.

Comment: Five Star is a great rating module, but the question is trying to solve a problem with the Relation module. I'm building the rating this way because my app will use a similar relationship to track "shares" "views" and other types of things too. Also, I'm creating the relationships with Services so the widget capability of Five Star isn't necessary.